# unique solution of system ordinary differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let

$\dot x(t)=x^2(t)+x(t)y(t)$

$\dot y(t)=-x(t)y(t)$

Under the hypotheses $|x(t)|<a(t), |y(t)|<b(t)$, for some $a,b \in C_0$, initial conditions $x(0), y(0)$ bounded by $a,b$, the Picard Lindelof theorem condition is satisfied , since the derivative matrix of the right hand-side column is continuous and, thus, system has a unique solution. How could we find a unique solution? Is there a way to calculate solutions under constraints in mathematica?

Comment: 1. You need an initial condition to use the theorem you mention. 2. Further, the same requires the function $(x,y) \mapsto (x^2 + xy, -xy)$ to be uniformly Lipschitz cont. which doesn't seem to follow from your hypothesis.

Comment: The initial conditions should be within the bounds. $a$ and $b$ are supposed continuous. The hypothesis makes the derivative matrix $(x,y) \mapsto Df$ continuous, which is equivalent to the Lipschitz continuity of $f=(x^2+xy,-xy)$

Comment: $Df= $$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
   2x+y & x \\
        -y & -x  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Hm, it is a polynomial (quadratic, homogeneous, non-linear) system! That's the best differentiability you can hope for. Why wouldn't it have existence and uniqueness? The Picard-Lindelof Theorem seems to apply to this system big time.

Comment: Matrix derivative $Df$ that contains the partial derivatives should be continuous, and this is achieved if its elements are bounded. If its elements are not bounded (e.g if we have finite escape time), then the matrix derivative is not continuous and therefore the column $f$ is not Lipschitz continuous. In this case, the solution is not unique.

Comment: No, this is not true. All you need is continuity of the derivatives and in this case they are more than continuous. They are polynomial and thus infinitely differentiable. No boundedness of the derivatives is needed. If you have global boundedness, i.e. global Lipschitz property, then you can guarantee that the solutions exist and can be extended for all times $t$. It's a sufficient but not a necessary condition. This system is actually integrable and solvable in elementary functions. I can write down the solutions explicitly. I don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: But mathematica produces two distinct solutions.

Comment: I am guessing mathematica produces two formulas for the general solution (solution depending on initial conditions = depending on parameters) depending on whether the solutions is above or below the $x-$axis. The $x-$axis is the trajectory of a solution itself. Existence and uniqueness of solution means that for any choice of initial points $(x_0,y_0)$ on the plane there exists a unique solution of the system that passes through that point when $t=0$ (or it could be $t=t_0$ if you wish).

Comment: Have you tried to solve the equation yourself, without using mathematica? It is a very good exercise in changing variables and understanding the dynamics of the system.